# Need <br/> tag before Continue reading → inside every <p> tag where i have that text Continue reading →

Tags: jquery

Right now my output is coming like that

```
 <p>text text text  Continue reading →</p>
  <p>text1 tex1t text1  Continue reading →</p>
  <p>text2 text2 text2  Continue reading →</p>
```

But i need like that

```
 <p>text text text <br/> Continue reading →</p>
  <p>text1 tex1t text1 <br/>  Continue reading →</p>
  <p>text2 text2 text2 <br/> Continue reading →</p>
```

I am not getting how to do it in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find and replace method like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pswcb/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("p").each(function() {
    $(this).html( 
        $(this).html().replace(/\sContinue\sreading\s→/g , 
            "<br /> Continue reading →"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CSS pseudo elements :

```
<p>text text text  <span></span>Continue reading →</p>

p span:before
{
     content : "\A";
     white-space : pre;
}
```

The JQuery solution is safer because ::before is not supported in old IEs, but the CSS solution works without JS.